# Iterating through a unicode string in Python

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

I've got an issue with iterating through unicode strings, character by character, with python.

```
print "w: ",word
for c in word:
    print "word: ",c
```

This is my output

```
w:  文本
word:  ? 
word:  ?
word:  ?
word:  ?
word:  ?
word:  ?
```

My desired output is:

```
文
本
```

When I use len(word) I get 6. Apparently each character is 3 unicode chunks.

So, my unicode string is successfully stored in the variable, but I cannot get the characters out. I have tried using encode('utf-8'), decode('utf-8) and codecs but still cannot obtain any good results. This seems like a simple problem but is frustratingly hard for me.

Hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
word = "文本"
print(word)
for each in unicode(word,"utf-8"):
    print(each)
```

Output:

```
文本
文
本
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! However I'm still getting an error "'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u5f02' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)". Could it be that my file isn't read as unicode at the first place? I'm using this line of code to read the file: fileContent = codecs.open('fileName.txt,'UTF-8').read()

Comment: @charpi you must have mixed Unicode strings with 8 bit strings?

Comment: @charpi https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html You are using `open` wrong, you need to specify `encoding='UTF-8'`. Not just `'UTF-8'` because you are setting the `mode` parameter

Comment: The error checking didn't catch it in this case because it only checks the start of the mode string which is a bit buggy maybe. But to prove this, trying with a different encoding you get the appropriate error: `codecs.open('data.txt', 'latin5').read()` `ValueError: mode string must begin with one of 'r', 'w', 'a' or 'U', not 'latin5'`.

Comment: @charpi use `fileContent = codecs.open('fileName.txt','r','utf-8').read()` instead

Comment: @jamylak thanks! I've changed it, but the error is still there :(

Comment: This is an extract of my file after I split it using \n.

Comment: [u'"\u5f02\u8bae:\u6124\u6012"', u'"\u953b\u70bc:\u75b2\u52b3"', u'"\u60b2:\u773c\u6cea"', u'"\u6d74:\u6e05\u6d01\u5ea6"', u'"\u75c5\u83cc:\u75c5"', u'"\u75c5:\u75c5"', u'"\u6696\u6c14:\u70ed\u60c5"', u'"\u4f24:\u75bc\u75db"']

Comment: Thanks guys. It works after some trial and error, I'll post what I did :)

Comment: @charpi , the list contents are already in unicode , you don't have to decode it again using `unicode()`

Answer (score 2):

The code I used which works is this

```
fileContent = codecs.open('fileName.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
#...split by whitespace to get words..
for c in word:
        print(c.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: you can also directly `print(c)` , no need to encode again since the file contents you commented were already in unicode

Answer (score 2):

you should convert the *word* from *string* type to *unicode*:

```
print "w: ",word
for c in word.decode('utf-8'):
    print "word: ",c
```

Answer (score 1):

For python 3 this is what works:

```
import unicodedata

word = "文本"
word = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', word)
for char in word:
    print(char)
```